# searching fullname in one columnsearch

Tags: php, yii2

I have query in my BlogSearch where i join relation with User. In my Column User I want to searchin User by his fullname. This is my code of BlogSearch.

```
$query->joinWith('relUser');

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'Id' => $this->Id,
            'CreatedAt' => $this->CreatedAt,
        ]);


$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Title', $this->Title])
             ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Description', $this->Description])
             ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'User.Name', $this->Rel_User])
             ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'User.Surname', $this->Rel_User]);
```

Comment: What mean don't work ,, error ,, wrong result ?.. please show all the search model

Comment: how can i concat my columns into one?

Comment: Where you want concat the columns ,,, sqlquery? ,,, gridview columns)?  update your question with a proper explanation and show Your related searchModel ,  controllerAction and view please ..

Comment: i tried to explain my problem in my first post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your model Blog add a getter for fullName

```
public function getFullName() {
   return $this->relUser.>Name . ' ' . $this->relUser.Surname;
 }
```

Add to your  BlogSearc a field for filter

```
class BlogSearch extends Blog
{

  public $fullName;

 /* setup rules */
 public function rules() {
    return [
    /* your other rules */
    [['fullName'], 'safe']
  ];
}
```

then use this for query  instead of your JoinWith

```
        $query->joinWith(['relUser' => function ($q) {
            $q->where( 'UrUser.Name  LIKE "%' .$this->fullName . '%"' . ' OR UrUser.Name LIKE "%' . $this->fullName . '%"' );
        }]);
```

and in your gridView you can use directly the fullName field

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            'Title',
            'Description',
            'fullName',
            //'CreatedAt',
            // 'IsDeleted',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

For Name and Surname in  the same time try  adding

```
   ->orFilterWhere(['like', 'concat(UrUser.Name, " " , UrUser.Surname) ', $this->fullName]);
```

Comment: i have database exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'relUser.Name' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `urBlog` LEFT JOIN `urUser` ON `urBlog`.`Rel_User` = `urUser`.`Id` WHERE relUser.Name LIKE "%%" OR relUser.Surname LIKE "%%"   This exception is form this query. Could You told me in this query 'relUser.Name',  'relUser' is name of relation or name of table?

Comment: In the  $query->anWhere(...) you must set the proper table name ... could be is UrUser   .. i have update the answer  ..

Comment: Unfortunately, search does not work when i put some letters its notting happened

Comment: check if you have fullName , safe in rules (searchModel)

Comment: i msut used to .$this->relUser['Name'] instead of $this->relUser.>Name becosue i had 'Trying to get property of non-object' but it still not work for me

Comment: I'm sorry is fullName and not relUser->name ... i have update the answer

Comment: problem must be in other place becouse it still only refresh page i tried to use a different ways in this query but it still the same.

Comment: The error of property of non-object is solved or not ..?

Comment: Try var_dump the query performed an see if there are some condtion that don't permit the correct result ..

Comment: i var_dump this query but i dont know that You want only var_dump($query) or this which i put in my first post

Comment: Looking at your code i see you have  the var public $fullName in model and not in modelSearch .. You should delete this from model and add it to modelSearch ... in model you should add the getter function (getFullName())  like i suggest in my answer... i hope this is clear .. otherwise it does not work

Comment: this modelSearch is old I have there this public var

Comment: i sho my modelSearch now

Comment: And you have removed $fullName in model and added a getter function ...right,,? have you the fullName attruibute in grid ?

Comment: thank for You patience i update my first post AFTER EDIT

Comment: Thank for reply then the query work with part of the text (name or surname) but not with a string composed wth name and surname  . please confirm ..

Comment: Just a minor and a last try....  i have update the answer adding a space beween Name and Surname ..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

`$query->select('id, CONCAT_WS(' ', Name, Surname) as name')
        ->from('customer')
        ->where('CONCAT_WS(' ', Name, Surname) LIKE "%' . $search .'%"')
        ->limit(10)`